# getting PLSQL numeric or value error for below code

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
    Declare 
            TYPE cur_type IS REF CURSOR;
            v_owner varchar2(40);
             v_table_name varchar2(40);
             v_column_name varchar2(100);
            ln_col_variable VARCHAR2(20000) := Null;
            sql_fetch       VARCHAR2(30000) := Null;
             l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
             col_var  varchar2(2000);

               enquiry_cur cur_type;

              /* First cursor */
                  CURSOR get_tables IS
                  SELECT DISTINCT  tbl.table_name
                   FROM user_tab_columns tbl
                   WHERE tbl.column_name='ENQUIRY_NO';

              /* Second cursor */
                        CURSOR get_columns IS
                         SELECT DISTINCT col.column_name
                         FROM user_tab_columns col
                          -- WHERE col.owner = v_owner
                        WHERE col.table_name = v_table_name;

                  BEGIN
                      dbms_output.enable(1000000);
                    -- Open first cursor
                          OPEN get_tables;

                   LOOP
                 FETCH get_tables INTO  v_table_name;
                 exit when  get_tables%notfound;
                 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_table_name);
                 dbms_output.put_line('----------------------');


                         -- Open second cursor
                  OPEN get_columns;
                  LOOP
               FETCH get_columns INTO v_column_name;
                exit when get_columns%notfound;
               dbms_output.put_line(v_column_name);
               ln_col_variable :=ln_col_variable||','||v_column_name;

               col_var:=replace(substr(ln_col_variable,1,1),',','*');


               --dbms_output.put_line(col_var);
                 /*  Loop
         ln_col_variable :=ln_col_variable||','||v_column_name;


                      End Loop;*/
         -- ln_col_variable :=ln_col_variable||sysdate;
         --  sql_fetch       := 'Select '||ln_col_variable||'           From '||v_table_name;
             -- dbms_output.put_line(sql_fetch);
                          END LOOP;
                sql_fetch := 'Select '||col_var||' From '||v_table_name;

           OPEN enquiry_cur FOR sql_fetch ;


                  l_xmltype := XMLTYPE(enquiry_cur);
                 dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);
                  CLOSE get_columns;

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE get_tables;

         EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN  raise_application_error(-20001,'An              encountered  '||SQLCODE||'        -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
                   end ;
```

I m getting Plsql  numeric or value error for line 74 . want to get the xml output for sql_fetch   string .  used utl_files  but  couldn't get the xml output  .The tables  are only  dynamically  known .the  table structure also  is known at compile time

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors to your code. You need to correct that before you could solve your actual error. Your cursor `get_columns` is parameterised and you are not passing any value to it. See below:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE cur_type IS REF CURSOR;

   v_owner           VARCHAR2 (40);
   v_table_name      VARCHAR2 (40);
   v_column_name     VARCHAR2 (100);
   ln_col_variable   VARCHAR2 (20000) := NULL;
   sql_fetch         VARCHAR2 (30000) := NULL;
   l_xmltype         XMLTYPE;
   col_var           VARCHAR2 (2000);

   enquiry_cur       cur_type;

   /* First cursor */
   CURSOR get_tables
   IS
      SELECT DISTINCT tbl.table_name
        FROM user_tab_columns tbl
       WHERE tbl.column_name = 'COL1';

   /* Second cursor */
   CURSOR get_columns(v_table_name varchar)
   IS
      SELECT DISTINCT col.column_name
        FROM user_tab_columns col
       -- WHERE col.owner = v_owner
       WHERE col.table_name = v_table_name; --<--using a variable here
BEGIN
   --DBMS_OUTPUT.enable (1000000);

   -- Open first cursor
   OPEN get_tables;

   LOOP
      FETCH get_tables INTO v_table_name;

      EXIT WHEN get_tables%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_table_name);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('----------------------');


      -- Open second cursor
      OPEN get_columns(v_table_name); --<--You need to pass parameter to cursor

      LOOP

         FETCH get_columns INTO v_column_name;

         EXIT WHEN get_columns%NOTFOUND;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_column_name);
         ln_col_variable := ln_col_variable || ',' || v_column_name;

         col_var := REPLACE (SUBSTR (ln_col_variable, 1, 1), ',', '*');
      --dbms_output.put_line(col_var);
        /*  Loop
             ln_col_variable :=ln_col_variable||','||v_column_name;


             End Loop;*/
      -- ln_col_variable :=ln_col_variable||sysdate;
      --  sql_fetch       := 'Select '||ln_col_variable||'           From '||v_table_name;
      -- dbms_output.put_line(sql_fetch);
      END LOOP;

      sql_fetch := 'Select ' || col_var || ' From ' || v_table_name;

      OPEN enquiry_cur FOR sql_fetch;


      l_xmltype := XMLTYPE (enquiry_cur);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_xmltype.getClobVal);

      CLOSE get_columns;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE get_tables;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      raise_application_error (
         -20001,
            'An              encountered  '
         || SQLCODE
         || '        -ERROR- '
         || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Once the code is corrected, you need to make sure that all the tables you are referring in cursor `get_tables` should have at least 1 row else you will get `PL/SQL: numeric or value error`.

Output:

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> /
TABL1
----------------------
COL1
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <COL1>1</COL1>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>

<COL1>2</COL1>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <COL1>A</COL1>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <COL1>B2</COL1>

</ROW>
</ROWSET>

TABL2
----------------------
COL1
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <COL1>1</COL1>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: My second cursor is not parameterized as I  have checked the  code  above .In the declare section    CURSOR get_columns IS
     SELECT DISTINCT col.column_name
     FROM user_tab_columns col
    -- WHERE col.owner = v_owner
    WHERE col.table_name = v_table_name;
so I am not using parameterized cursor

Comment: in  the executable section    below is the code OPEN get_columns;
     LOOP
          FETCH get_columns INTO v_column_name;
          exit when get_columns%notfound;
          dbms_output.put_line(v_column_name);

Comment: @Alka. I guess you need to understand what is parameterised cusor. fyi how can oracle evelaute this `WHERE col.table_name = v_table_name;` from where it should understand the value for `v_table_name`.  Read through the code i posted. Its working fine. Just follow what i mentioned.

Comment: I have  used the above code .made changes for parameterized  cursor  as advised .but still getting the Plsql numeric value error in the xml part .if I comment  the xml  section then the block works

Comment: @Alka. Did you check if you all the tables have atleast 1 row which you are referring in your cursor? You can see that i shared the output and its working fine with me

Comment: No  all tables  do not  necessarily have  1 row ..some tables have zero rows for one given enquiry_no ..but I also need    to know how to put the where clause   ie   here  "sql_fetch := 'Select ' || col_var || ' From ' || v_table_name;"    if  I write  sql_fetch := 'Select ' || col_var || ' From ' || v_table_name  ||  'where  enquiry_no =:1';  then this gives error  not all variables bound .. so how do I put  my where condition   .   I  will fetch records   in  select *  from table_name where enquiry_no='xxxx' in the simple output   recordwise

Comment: @Alka. This seem a sepearate question. You can close the current question and put this in a seperate question mentioning clearly your requirement.